# Problema con codigo en C

Tags: c

Compañeros tengo una gran duda, estoy realizando un código que me permita realizar el registro de calificaciones con A o F en un arreglo, pero al ejecutarlo si ingreso un numero menor o igual a 7 me da los datos correctamente pero si ingreso un numero mayor a 8 me deja capturar las calificaciones pero a la hora de contar se deja de ejecutar

```
#include<stdio.h>

#include<string.h>


int captura(int num,char arreglo[]);
int cuenta(char arreglo[]);
int main()
{
    printf("Bienvenido, este programa que realiza el estudio de los alumnos que realizaron el examen\n");
    int num;
    char arreglo[num];
    captura(num,arreglo);
    cuenta(arreglo);
    
}

int captura(int num,char arreglo[])
{
    printf("Ingrese la cantidad de calificaciones a capturar: ");
    scanf("%i",&num);
    
    for (int i=0;i<num;i++)
        {
            printf("\nIngrese la calificacion obtenida numero %i (A / F): ",i+1);
            scanf("%s",&arreglo[i]);
        }
        
        
}

int cuenta(char arreglo[])
{
  int i,aprob=0,reprob=0;
  for (i = 0; arreglo[i] !='\0';i++)

    {
        printf("%i",i);
        char letraActual = arreglo[i];
        if(letraActual== 'A' ){
        
        aprob++;
    }   if(letraActual == 'F'){
        reprob++;
    }
    
  
}
  printf("\nEl numero de estudiantes que aprobaron: %i",aprob);
  printf("\nEl numero de estudiantes que reprobaron: %i",reprob);
}
```

Comment: ¿qué valor tiene `num` al momento de crearse `arreglo` en `main`?

Comment: Cuando declaro num no tiene un valor como tal, ya que en la función captura(), el usuario da el numero de caracteres (en este caso calificaciones) que tendrá la variable num

Comment: ¿Las calificaciones son letras de la 'A' a la 'F'? o ¿simplemente son 2 letras 'A' y 'F'? Si son letras de la 'A' hasta la 'F', ¿Cuál es la nota aprobatoria?

Comment: Son solo dos letras, que en este caso es A de aprobado y F de reprobado

Answer (score 2):

Hay dos errores en esta declaración en `main`:

```
int num;
char arreglo[num];
```

Una es que C los arreglos deben declararse con un valor constante, conocido al momento de la compilación, lo que no es el caso aqui. El compilador no puede saber que tamaño tiene el arreglo.

Además estás declarando un arreglo de dimensión indeterminada, pues `num` no ha sido inicializado explicitamente, y puede contener cualquier cosa. Todo funcionara bien mientras este valor aleatorio sea mayor que la cantidad deseada, pero en otro caso, fallara.

Si quieres crear un arreglo de dimensión arbitraria, debes usar `malloc`, pero esa es otra historia.

En la función captura hay dos problemas:

```
int captura(int num, char arreglo[]) {
    printf("Ingrese la cantidad de calificaciones a capturar: ");
    scanf("%i", &num);

    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        printf("\nIngrese la calificacion obtenida numero %i (A / F): ", i + 1);
        scanf("%s", &arreglo[i]);
    }
}
```

Primero, estas recibiendo `num` como parámetro, pero no usas su valor, sino que inmediatamente lo reemplazas con el valor ingresado por el usuario. Entonces, no tiene ningún sentido pasar `num` como parámetro.

La otra falla es que no pones un \0 para marcar el final de `arreglo`. Entonces, cuando recorres el arreglo para contar, pues seguir hasta el infinito.

**Solución**

Declara `arreglo` de tamaño constante. Un curso no puede tener más de 30 alumnos (por ejemplo), asi que simplemente definimos una constante.

El programa quedaría asi (no incluye tratamiento de errores):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int captura(char arreglo[]);
int cuenta(char arreglo[]);

#define MAX_ALUMNOS 30

int main() {
    printf("Bienvenido, este programa que realiza el estudio de los alumnos que realizaron el examen\n");
    char arreglo[MAX_ALUMNOS];
    captura(arreglo);
    cuenta(arreglo);
}

int captura(char arreglo[]) {
    int num;
    printf("Ingrese la cantidad de calificaciones a capturar: ");
    scanf("%i", &num);

    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        printf("\nIngrese la calificacion obtenida numero %i (A / F): ", i + 1);
        scanf("%s", &arreglo[i]);
    }
    arreglo[num] = 0;
}

int cuenta(char arreglo[]) {
    int i, aprob = 0, reprob = 0;
    for (i = 0; arreglo[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        printf("%i", i);
        char letraActual = arreglo[i];
        if (letraActual == 'A') {
            aprob++;
        }
        if (letraActual == 'F') {
            reprob++;
        }
    }
    printf("\nEl numero de estudiantes que aprobaron: %i", aprob);
    printf("\nEl numero de estudiantes que reprobaron: %i", reprob);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ese programa tiene dos problemas:

**1.-** Probé el código y apenas inicie el programa, *dejo de funcionar* y claro, esto se debe porque el problema radica aquí:

```c
int num;
char arreglo[num];
```

Nunca inicializas la variable `num`, por lo tanto, su contenido puede ser cualquiera y si es un **valor muy GRANDE**, puede provocar un [desbordamiento de pila](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desbordamiento_de_pila) (porque el tamaño del *array* es excesivamente grande) y esto ocasiona que el proceso actual aborte inmediatamente.

Una posible **solución** sería pedir los números de elementos en la función `main` y de este modo, aseguramos de forma adecuada la longitud del *array*:

```c
int main()
{
    printf("Bienvenido, este programa que realiza el estudio de los alumnos que realizaron el examen\n");
    int num;
    printf("Ingrese la cantidad de calificaciones a capturar: ");
    scanf("%i",&num);
    char arreglo[num + 1];
    
    captura(num, arreglo);
    cuenta(arreglo);
}
```

**Nota:** Hay que dejar un espacio para el caracter nulo.

**2.-** En esta línea estás provocando un [desbordamiento de búfer](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desbordamiento_de_b%C3%BAfer):

```c
scanf("%s", &arreglo[i]);
```

Cuando se llegue a la última posición del *array*, la función `scanf` escribirá el caracter nulo en una dirección adyacente (en una dirección próxima del último elemento del *array*) y así es como nos pasamos de los límites del *array*.

Aquí podrías suceder dos cosas:

- Sobrescribimos la propia memoria del programa (esto es difícil de depurar).
- Intentamos acceder a una dirección que ya está en uso por otro proceso, en este caso, lo normal es que el sistema aborte el proceso actual.

Una posible **solución** es pedir al usuario únicamente un caracter y no una cadena:

```c
//Se deja un espacio para ignorar el salto de línea si es que se encuentra en el búfer del teclado.
scanf(" %c", &arreglo[i]);
```

**Observaciones:**

**1.-** Según el estándar, la función `main` debe retornar un valor de tipo `int`:

**2.-** Las funciones `captura` y `cuenta` en ningún momento retornan un valor, entonces deberían ser definidos como un procedimiento (de tipo `void`).

**3.-** Cuando declaras una función no necesitas especificar el nombre de cada parámetro.

**4.-** No debes incluir cabeceras que no uses, por ejemplo, en ningún momento utilizas alguna función de `string.h`.

Sí seguimos con las observaciones, el código completo quedaría así:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void captura(int, char[]);
void cuenta(char []);

//Se agrega "void" porque la función NO acepta argumentos.
int main(void)
{
    printf("Bienvenido, este programa que realiza el estudio de los alumnos que realizaron el examen\n");
    int num;
    printf("Ingrese la cantidad de calificaciones a capturar: ");
    scanf("%i",&num);
    char arreglo[num + 1];
    captura(num, arreglo);
    cuenta(arreglo);
    return 0;
}

void captura(int num, char arreglo[])
{
    for (int i=0; i < num;i++)
    {
        printf("\nIngrese la calificacion obtenida numero %i (A / F): ",i+1);
        scanf(" %c", &arreglo[i]);
    }
    //Asignamos el caracter nulo.
    arreglo[num] = '\0';
}

void cuenta(char arreglo[])
{
    int i, aprob=0, reprob=0;
    for (i = 0; arreglo[i] != '\0';i++)
    {
        printf("%i", i);
        char letraActual = arreglo[i];
        if(letraActual== 'A' )
            aprob++;
       if(letraActual == 'F')
            reprob++;
    }
    printf("\nEl numero de estudiantes que aprobaron: %i", aprob);
    printf("\nEl numero de estudiantes que reprobaron: %i", reprob);
}
```

**Observaciones extras:**

Lo que has hecho en esta línea:

```c
char arreglo[num];
```

Se llama [VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) (Variable-length array), a pesar que en el estándar [C99](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99) se incluyó esta característica, no lo se debe usar por dos posibles razones:

**1.-** No todos los compiladores tienen soporte para VLA. Por lo tanto, el código deja de ser portable.

**2.-** Sí el tamaño del *array* es grande, puede provocar un desbordamiento de pila.

La forma correcta de crear un *array* cuya longitud se obtiene en tiempo de ejecución, es usando memoria dinámica con [malloc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/) o [calloc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/calloc/).

El código anterior se lo podría convertir de esta manera (sin uso de los VLA):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> //malloc, free

void captura(int, char[]);
void cuenta(char []);

//Se agrega "void" porque la función NO acepta argumentos.
int main(void)
{
    printf("Bienvenido, este programa que realiza el estudio de los alumnos que realizaron el examen\n");
    int num;
    char* arreglo;
    printf("Ingrese la cantidad de calificaciones a capturar: ");
    scanf("%i", &num);
    arreglo = malloc((num + 1) * sizeof(char));
    if(arreglo != NULL)
    {
        captura(num, arreglo);
        cuenta(arreglo);
    }
    //Libera la memoria.
    free(arreglo);
    return 0;
}

void captura(int num, char arreglo[])
{
    for (int i=0; i < num;i++)
    {
        printf("\nIngrese la calificacion obtenida numero %i (A / F): ",i+1);
        scanf(" %c", &arreglo[i]);
    }
    //Asignamos el caracter nulo.
    arreglo[num] = '\0';
}

void cuenta(char arreglo[])
{
    int i, aprob=0, reprob=0;
    for (i = 0; arreglo[i] != '\0';i++)
    {
        printf("%i", i);
        char letraActual = arreglo[i];
        if(letraActual== 'A' )
            aprob++;
       if(letraActual == 'F')
            reprob++;
    }
    printf("\nEl numero de estudiantes que aprobaron: %i", aprob);
    printf("\nEl numero de estudiantes que reprobaron: %i", reprob);
}
```

Como verás, el código no cambió mucho.

Answer (score 1):

Uno de los problemas de tu código es que estás malgastando un bucle, es decir, realizas 2 bucles cuando realmente con 1 te basta.

Otro problema es el nombre de las variables escogidas. ¿Te penalizan por usar nombres coherentes? Las variables deben tener un nombre significativo, que represente el valor que las mismas *contienen*.

Por último, tu pregunta tiene etiqueta [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), entonces usa código de [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b).

Una forma que se me ocurre puedes hacer que el programa funcione (sin detenerme a mirar errores en la entrada del usuario) podría ser la siguiente:

1. Creamos una función llamada `calcularAprobados` aunque la misma devolverá no sólo los aprobados sino los reprobados, en un arreglo o `array`.
2. Esta función recibirá como argumento un valor entero que indica la cantidad de calificaciones a procesar y un arreglo para almacenar las mismas.
3. Se itera la cantidad de calificaciones a procesar y se le pregunta al usuario en cada iteración la calificación (letra 'A' o letra 'F') y se van almacenando en el arreglo.
4. A medida que se van almacenando las calificaciones, se van contando la cantidad de aprobados y reprobados.
5. Al finalizar el bucle, se devuelve la cantidad de aprobados y reprobados en un arreglo de 2 posiciones.
6. Se muestra el resultado.

El código puede verse así:

```cpp
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int *calcularAprobados(int num, char arreglo[])
{
  int cantAprobados = 0;
  int cantReprobados = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
  {
    cout << "\nIngrese la calificacion obtenida numero "<< i + 1 << " (A / F): ";
    cin >> arreglo[i];
    switch(arreglo[i])
    {
      case 'A':
        cantAprobados++;
        break;
      case 'F':
        cantReprobados++;
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  }
  static int resultado[2] = {cantAprobados, cantReprobados};
  return resultado;     
}

int main()
{
    int numeroCalificaciones;
    int *resultado;
    cout << "Bienvenido, este programa que realiza el estudio de los alumnos que realizaron el examen." << endl;
    cout << "Ingrese la cantidad de calificaciones a capturar: ";
    cin >> numeroCalificaciones;
    char calificaciones[numeroCalificaciones];
    resultado = calcularAprobados(numeroCalificaciones, calificaciones);
    cout << "La cantidad de aprobados es: " << resultado[0] << endl;
    cout << "La cantidad de reprobados es: " << resultado[1] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Como puedes observar, no se realiza una verificación de errores en la entrada del usuario, ya que sólo se contempla que se introducirán caracteres 'A' y 'F' en mayúsculas.

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.